# Need advice on tracking objects in hand using TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I am trying to develop a model which detects the items that are picked up by a user from a basket. Is this achievable using Tensorflow? My doubt is since the basket would contain the same items the user picks up (say fruits), is it possible to report the product that in the user's hand(the products that are picked up by the user) in real-time, rather than the items in the basket? Please advice on what would be a good starting point to achieve this.

I have read and watched general object detection methods using Tensor Flow and various models but nothing seems to deal with a similar solution or I am unable to co-relate. If there are any tutorials on achieving, the links for the same would be even more helpful. Thanks in advance. Please bear with me if my question is naive, I am still a newbie at ML and Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

It is achievable using Tensorflow. First consider how you would approach the problem. Since you need to distinguish between objects inside basket you will need ANN with some **basic classification** and **object detection**.

Here are some links to get you started:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification
- https://www.edureka.co/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-tutorial/

Good luck!